# jQuery response working in DreamWeaver but not in Browser

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, response

I have a problem when trying to get response from URL or PHP script. When I click on a button that runs this function clicked() it gives normal response in DreamWeaver but when clicked in browser it returns error. I've searched answers but nothing really helped.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Log In</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>      
</head>
// I've deleted buttons and other stuff from this example code so it can be easier to read
<script language="javascript">

function clicked(){
$.ajax("test.php", {
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'text',
        success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            var returned_data = data;
            alert("returned_data ="+returned_data);
        },
        error: function( req, status, err ) {
         alert( 'something went wrong', status, err );
        }
    });

</script>


</html>
```

PHP script is working fine, some other problem is here but I can't seem to see it.

Comment: What error do you get?

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a closing brace at the end of your script.
it should be:

```
<script language="javascript">

 function clicked(){
     $.ajax("test.php", {
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'text',
        success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        var returned_data = data;
        alert("returned_data ="+returned_data);
      },
      error: function( req, status, err ) {
          alert( 'something went wrong', status, err );
      }
    });
 }

</script>
```

Comment: @NemanjaRankovic can you please post the error it is giving you.

Comment: the problem is with your php script url.

Comment: you are using a node server to serve a php file?

Comment: but your ajax uri should be something like [http://localhost:1333/yourscript](http://localhost:1333/yourscript)

Answer (score 0):

Your code works on Dreamweaver because it has a built in Apache server, although you are not using one in your production environment.